# How to trigger a function/script for new data in a Redis stream

Tags: redis, lua

I've written a script python that reads data from a stream and perform some operations. Now, I want to perform these operations in-memory so I wrote a LUA script that replicates python script steps. I'm not an expert in LUA scripting, but this is the code:

```
-- LUA FUNCTION FOR REDIS

-- DEFINE STREAM NAME
stream_name = "sim-stream"


-- SEARCH FILES FUNCTION
search_files = function(tabella, snapshot, event_type = "C", doc_id = "", doc_ref = "")
    start_time
    for _, key in ipairs(snapshot) do
        if key != stream_name then
        
            local value = cjson.decode(redis.call('GET', key))
            if (event_type == "C") and (value["eventType"] == event_type) then 
            
                if (value["reference"] == doc_ref) then
                    
                    start_time = tonumber(value["eventTimestamp"])
                    event_type = "B"
                    doc_ref = value["id"]
                    -- update table values
                    tabella['C'] = value
                    tabella['latencies']['c_to_d'] = tabella["D"]["eventTimestamp"] - start_time
                    search_files(tabella, snapshot, event_type = event_type, doc_ref = doc_ref)
                end
            elseif (event_type == "B") and (value["eventType"] == event_type) then 
            
                if (value["reference"] == doc_ref) then
                    
                    start_time = tonumber(value["eventTimestamp"])
                    event_type = "A"
                    doc_id = value["id"]
                    -- update table values
                    tabella['B'] = value
                    tabella['latencies']['b_to_c'] = tabella["C"]["eventTimestamp"] - start_time
                    search_files(tabella, snapshot, event_type = event_type, doc_id = doc_id)
                end         
            elseif (event_type == "A") and (value["eventType"] == event_type) then 
            
                if (value["id"] == doc_id) then
                    
                    start_time = tonumber(value["eventTimestamp"])
                    -- update table values
                    tabella['A'] = value
                    tabella['latencies']['a_to_b'] = tabella["B"]["eventTimestamp"] - start_time
                    -- return start_time
                    return tabella
                end
            else 
            end
        end
    end

    -- return start_time
    return tabella
end


-- STARTING SCRIPT
-- get last ID
last_id = redis.call('XLEN', stream_name)


-- CHANGE NEXT LINE WITH TRIGGER EVENT
local k, d = redis.call('XREAD', 'STREAMS', stream_name, 'COUNT', 1, 'BLOCK', 0) 
local key = k[1][2][1]
local data = cjson.decode(d[1][2][2])

if redis.call("EXISTS", key) == 0 then

    redis.call('SET', last_id, cjson.encode(data))

    eventType = 'C'
    doc_id = ''
    doc_ref = ''

    if data['eventType'] == 'D' then
        end_time = tonumeric(data['eventTimestamp'])
        start_time = 0
        doc_ref = data['id']
        local snapshot = redis.call('KEYS', '*')
        
        
        output_table = {
          id = data["id"],
          reference = data["reference"],
          A = {},
          B = {},
          C = {},
          D = data,
          latencies = {
            a_to_b = 0,
            b_to_c = 0,
            c_to_d = 0
          }
        }

        -- start_time = search_files(output_table, snapshot = snapshot, event_type = eventType, doc_ref = doc_ref)
        output_table = search_files(output_table, snapshot = snapshot, event_type = eventType, doc_ref = doc_ref)
        if output_table['c_to_d'] != 0 then

            redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, output_table)
        end
    end
end
```

The values published in the stream are json files (or dictionaries if you prefer), eachone has a timestamp and I calculate difference between timestamps from file to file based on file type and related ID's. I attached the code only for completion but if there's something wrong and you would tell me I really appreciate.

Let's go to the problem.
I used a `while True` loop for tests but in production I want to trigger this script for every element that arrives to the stream and replace the line `redis.call('XREAD', 'STREAMS', stream_name, 'COUNT', 1, 'BLOCK', 0)`. I think that's necessary but if I'm wrong correct me.

I know that I should use Pub/Sub to perform this operation, but I don't know exactly how to do..
I could copy the code in `FUNCTION LOAD ..` command and then run the function with `FCALL`, but how can I do this everytime new data arrives to the stream?
Or, could I `SUBSCRIBE` but how can I run the function?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might want to check RedisGears - see: https://oss.redis.com/redisgears/

Comment: Or better check RedisGears 2.0 https://github.com/RedisGears/RedisGears